# 403 response when sending POST data via cURL

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm trying to send some data to a custom built API that was built by a web development agency.  The api is pretty straight forward, and all that I require to do is authorise myself with an authorisation basic header and submit a payload which is just JSON data.

The problem is that the API is responding with 403 every time I send a POST request using cURL. Is there any way that my code could be causing this? or is it an error that is caused by the API/API server? Regardless if the JSON payload is correctly formatted or not, it should still return with a 200 response.

The request is pretty straight forward -

```
<?php
//I've removed the actual username and password
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('username:password'));
$empty_array = array();
//Create empty json as an example
$json =  json_encode($empty_array);
$url = "https://website.com/import";

//start cURL
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

If I take out the POST data, then it will return with a 404 response. This is the correct behaviour if there is no POST data submitted to the url. (I get a 404 if I navigate to the url via a browser). So I have a theory that the server must have some kind of restrictions on accepting POST data.

Does my code seem correct or am I missing something glaringly obvious? I wan't to rule out that it's a problem caused by my end due to not being able to access the code/server for the API as that is beyond my control.

Comment: "Is there any way that my code could be causing this?" — Their API has to decide, based on your request, if you are authorised or not.

Comment: "is it an error that is provided by the API?" — Yes

Comment: "Does my code seem correct or am I missing something glaringly obvious?" – We don't know what the API you are using expects. You should talk to the people who developed it.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking but I just want to rule out if it's anything caused by my end, or perhaps some cURL setting I am missing... but to me everything seems OK unless I'm missing something glaringly obvious. I'm already talking to them, but if its a problem caused by my own code, then we will get charged for it, hence the reason why I would like validation that it's not something I'm causing.